# Booting/shutting down a Linux mini-PC via USB or Ethernet

Tags: linux, usb, ethernet, power-management

I am using a T8 Ace Magician mini-PC running Debian Linux for embedded system purposes - because of that the power button that comes on the box will not be easily accessible.

Is it possible to power this device on and off from another device connected to it by USB or Ethernet cable? I am perfectly willing to implement a software program on both ends to make it work manually, but not in a position to necessarily design my own circuit board.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a BMC (Baseboard Management Controller) to remotely power the device. A BMC is a piece of hardware and as I am unfamiliar with T8 Ace Magician mini-PC, I am unsure if you will be able to install it, but hopefully this puts you on the right track.